# Use MySQL to calculate difference between two entries in the same table

Tags: mysql

I have a series of meter reading stored in a table, each is identified by a building ID, a meter ID and the time at which it was recorded.

For each entry I would like to search for the entry that has the same ID numbers and the closest previous time, I would then like to use the previous time and the previous reading to calculate the length of the time step and the differential between the two readings.

so, I currently have:

`BuildingID | MeterID | Date_and_Time | Reading`

and I would like to produce:

`BuildingID | MeterID | Date_and_Time | Time_Since_Previous_Read | Accumulation_Since previous_Read`

two typical entries might look like this:

`1 | 1 | 2010-10-09 17:56:20 | 119.6`

`1 | 1 | 2010-10-09 18:01:08 | 157.4`

and I would like to produce:

`1 | 1 | 2010-10-09 18:01:08 | 00:04:48 | 37.8`

If no previous entry exists (i.e. for the first reading) i woudl like to rerun zeros for the time elapsed and the accumulation.

I would appreciate very much any help that could be offered on this, I made a concerted effort to find the answer in previous posts but to no avail, feel free to direct me to a good source if this has already been solved elsewhere.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```
SELECT a.BuildingID, a.MeterID, a.Date_and_Time,
  a.Date_and_Time-b.Date_and_Time AS `Time_Since_Previous_Read`,
  a.Reading-b.Reading AS `Accumulation`,
  MAX(b.Date_and_Time) AS `otherdateandtime`
FROM `TABLENAME` AS `a`, `TABLENAME` AS `b`
WHERE a.BuildingID = b.BuildingID AND a.MeterID = b.MeterID
  AND a.Date_and_Time>b.Date_and_Time
GROUP BY `a.Date_and_Time`
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately is does not seem to be working for me, it will produce results but they are quite odd and I think inaccurate (wrt what I am looking for). I did modify it a bit to wok with specific table and column names to:

Comment: `SELECT a.BuildingID, a.MeterID, a.DateTime,
  timediff(a.DateTime,b.DateTime) AS `Time_Since_Previous_Read`,
  a.Value-b.Value AS `Accumulation`,
  MAX(b.DateTime) AS `otherdateandtime`
FROM `meterdata_test` AS `a`, `meterdata_test` AS `b`
WHERE a.BuildingID = b.BuildingID AND a.MeterID = b.MeterID
  AND a.DateTime > b.DateTime
GROUP BY BuildingID & MeterID`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/* 1*/SELECT
/* 2*/ r_B.BuildingID, 
/* 3*/ r_B.MeterID, 
/* 4*/ r_B.Date_and_Time, 
/* 5*/ COALESCE(DATEDIFF(hh, r_A.Date_and_Time, r_B.Date_and_Time), 0) AS Time_Since_Previous_Read,
/* 6*/ COALESCE(r_B.Reading-r_A.Reading, 0) AS Accumulation_Since_Previous_Read
/* 7*/  FROM meterdata r_B
/* 8*/  LEFT OUTER JOIN meterdata r_A
/* 9*/  ON r_B.BuildingID = r_A.BuildingID AND r_B.MeterID = r_A.MeterID AND r_B.Date_and_Time > r_A.Date_and_Time
/*10*/  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT nonelater.Date_and_Time FROM meterdata nonelater WHERE nonelater.BuildingID = r_B.BuildingID AND nonelater.MeterID = r_B.MeterID AND nonelater.Date_and_Time > r_A.Date_and_Time AND nonelater.Date_and_Time < r_B.Date_and_Time)
/*11*/ORDER BY r_B.BuildingID, r_B.MeterID, r_B.Date_and_Time
```

Here's how the design works:

- **Lines 7 and 8**: the core of the query is a **self-JOIN** on the meterdata table. You need that to be able to find the difference between values in one row and values in another row. r_B is the later one, r_B the earlier one.
- **Line 8**: Making it a **LEFT OUTER JOIN** means that it works even if there isn't an earlier r_A row; that part of the join will return `NULL`s.
- **Line 9**: this **constrains the JOIN** to only join rows for the same building and meter, and makes sure the two rows are the right way around.
- **Line 10**: If you didn't change the join any more, you'd have each r_B row joining to every single past row. To make sure that **r_B matches only to the most recent past row**, this line checks that there isn't another row more recent than r_A.
- **Line 6**: this calculates the **difference between the readings**; if there isn't an earlier r_A row, this calculation will return `NULL`, so you need the `COALESCE` function to change that to zero.
- At **line 5**, it does the same thing to find the **time interval**. For this demo I've used the [SQL Server DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function which won't give you exactly what you want, because on MySQL it only has one option, to calculate the difference in days; you may be able to use the [INTERVAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_interval) function instead. Again, if there isn't a row r_A then `COALESCE` will change the `NULL` to zero.

Everything's there except for getting a time interval out in days, hours and minutes and formatting it nicely. Good luck with that.